# QLabel updated from slot call not updating

Tags: c++, qt

I have used the example (commonly known) of using a QLabel to display image data that I'm pulling off of a camera.  The relevant code is below :

```
    void myGUI::updatePic1(imgStructColorQt image)
{
    QImage img((const uchar*)image.data,BUFFER_XSIZE,BUFFER_YSIZE, COLOR_BUFFER_BYTE_SIZE*BUFFER_XSIZE, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    img = img.scaled(514,388);
    if (!img.isNull())
    {
        ui->cam1view->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        ui->cam1view->update();
        ui->cam1view->repaint();
        std::cout << "image updated!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "image is null" << std::endl;
}
```

Where `updatePic1` is a slot called about 30 times a second with updated image data.  My QLabel, cam1view, on my main GUI window displays the first image, but never updates after that.  I know that the slot is being called correctly as I see the console output displaying "image updated!" about 30 times a second.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the QLabel is not being updated?  I also know that the image data is actually changing, because I can print single pixels to the screen and observe that they are changing as I would expect when I take off and put on a lens cap.

Comment: Does the label update if you set text to it?

Answer (score 0):

Which thread is calling this slot?

Remember that if the QObject emitting the signal and the QObject receiving it live in the same  thread then the connection will be direct and not scheduled using an event queue.

It might be that your event thread is the one processing the loop that contain the emit. In this case your application will never update the GUI since it is locked processing your loop.

Are you doing the frames acquisition in a separate thread?

Comment: Yes, the frame acquisition and emit are in a separate thread, using the moveToThread() function as described here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details